# I bought a small 1 liter CO2 gas tank for carbonating drinks, where could I start to find a regulator valve for this tank?

Tags: carbonation

I need to modify this tank with a valve/pressure controler so I can use it to carbonate drinks.

Images of the tank included.

I would order online but i have no specification to get data from. What kind of store would sell valves like this? Hardware store, Plumbing store?

The supplier did not have any additional equipment for these tanks. Their main bussiness were large 50l propane tanks with different valves.

Thanks and sorry if my question is out of place here. I use stackoverflow a lot and just wanted to try my luck in some other of their sites (stackexchange guitar site helped me a lot).

In perfect case someone could link some online valve that would fit similar tanks so I have something to reference to.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgWav.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ib3V.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXcqB.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcenA.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the tank to Riga kinda grey/black market for useless parts and weird equipment (unofficial marketplace, created after the soviet union collapsed and somehow still exists). I found a specialist there on gas tank equipment and apparently I had bought a specific tank for refilling sodastream like devices with a different name in Europe.

His solution was to change the valve. But he was concerned that below it there would need to be a special screw like pin (I'm not using the right english terminology here). Anyways it was clear that an adapter like that doesnt exists.

So I emptied the tank manually, using a small screw driven into a large wooden table (outdoors). And then removed the built in valve. Under it is a standard thread. So now I just have to buy the standard valve to replace the one I removed (a few bucks) the regulator (also a few bucks), and the bottle holder. So a pretty cheap solution. Also gotta refill the tank, but there are many services for that available and my quantities are negligible.

Sorry for long post and bad english/wrong terminology. I just wanted to post this so if someone comes across this problem his solution is to simply empty the tank and remove the valve and then change it. The 1l tanks (from sodastram like devices) top valve part is unique and is the problem but the built in hidden part is completely standard. If you know the right place to buy these parts it will cost you nothing, just have to empty manually and then replace the details.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to your local welding shop, or where ever you can go to get the tank filled.  They'd probably be most likely to help you find the parts you need, and on top of that, they should be able to fill it for you too.  If you don't know where one is, but have a local homebrew store, they can likely tell you where they go for their keg setups.

Comment: I researched some local wielding stores I'll visit. I couldnt find a single homebrewing shop in Riga... which is kinda weird. Currently I'm looking at something called sodastream online, it's looks very familiar to my device, but it's a different manufactuerer. They have adaptors http://www.craftbrewer.com.au/shop/details.asp?PID=924 and online tutorials, but I dont think my goal is so complex.

Comment: I'm almost certain a welding store could tell you exactly what you'd need and likely even have the parts.  If they can't, that'd be shocking.  Judging by the adapter you linked, I would avoid ordering online because of the price and hassle of returns if it isn't the right one.  Any welding shop should be able to get you the right parts needed, or point you in the right direction otherwise.

Comment: Without any specification I would never order online. Thanks for your advice!